# External font doesn't load in Android 2.1

Tags: android, css, webview, font-face, typeface

I'm using a external TrueType font in an embedded HTML resource. The font is located in assets, at the same level than the HTML resource.

The font is loaded with CSS:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: MyExternalFont; 
    src: url('MyExternalFont.ttf'); 
}
body {
    font-family:MyExternalFont;
}
```

And the HTML resource is loaded as follows:

```
WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm");
```

This works fine in **Android 1.5**, **Android 1.6** and **Android 2.2**. It doesn't work in **Android 2.1**.

However, when I load the font and use it in a `TextView`, it works on all Android versions. I do it like this:

```
final Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "MyExternalFont.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(t);
```

What might be the problem?

(Unfortunately I can't upload the font because it's a paid font)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4448) for android 2.0 and 2.1. You can't use external fonts in WebView on the platforms, sorry.